# Emptying the from field in the email entity in CRM 2013 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

So im trying to empty the from field on the email entity whenever i load the page. I am trying to do so using a javascript. My code is as follows.

```
function emptyField(fieldName) {
    var personType = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).DataValue = [];
}
```

I have also tried with

```
function emptyField(fieldName) {
    var personType = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).DataValue = null;
}
```

None of these methods seem to work however. Can anyone tell me what i can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OOB functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_setValue) goes like this:

```
function emptyField(fieldName) {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).setValue(null);
}
```

Double-check the notes in the MSDN page:

> Updating an attribute using setValue will not cause the OnChange event handlers to run. If you want the OnChange event handlers to run you must use fireOnChange in addition to setValue.
>
> When Microsoft Dynamics CRM for tablets is not connected to the server setValue will not work.
>
> You cannot set the value of composite attributes. More information: Write scripts for composite attributes.

Comment: But since the from field on email is a party list it does not have a setValue method? 

Therefore i tried with the above code because of the following link https://sites.google.com/site/ranjitclub/working-with-datatypes-in-javascript

Comment: I just tried it and it gives the error. Object doesn't support property or method 'setValue'

Comment: Something else is probably broken in the code elsewhere. Debugging will take care of that.

Comment: For some reason it didnt work when i gave the from field as an input parameter

It did however when i used the following

function emptyField() {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("from").setValue(null);
}

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer will work. But it doesn't save the empty value to field. If you want to save it just add this code :

```js
function setValue(toSet) {
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('myField').setValue(toSet);
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute('myField').setSubmitMode('always');
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
}
```